# How to get lasts 15 posts of user wall via fql stream table?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm confused with this FQL query:

```
SELECT type,attachment,message,permalink,created_time
FROM stream
WHERE
  source_id = xxxxxx and
  actor_id= xxxxxx and
  type = 247
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 46
```

It returns empty. But when I try this:

```
SELECT type,attachment,message,permalink,created_time
FROM stream
WHERE
  source_id = xxxxxx and
  actor_id= xxxxxx and
  type = 247
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 50
```

It returns 1 record as I expect.

Is it because of the `LIMIT` or something else? How do I show the 15 posts of the user?

Comment: Can you post some sample data that you are using to test with and perhaps the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is a facebook quirk: some of the posts are "hidden" from the response. So the top 45 posts are all hidden (given the credetials you're using to get the posts) and 1 (one) of the next 5 are visible. So it only returns the visble one. Increase limit and you may get more.

No real work around except to not include the limit, and then to manually count and use the first 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WallPosts> posts = facebookClient.executeQuery("select strip_tags(message),type from stream where filter_key = 'others'",WallPosts.class);
Iterator<WallPosts> postIterator = posts.iterator();
int wallCount = 0;
while (postIterator.hasNext()) {
  if (wallCount == 15) break;
  WallPosts post = postIterator.next();
  if (post.message != null) { // if message is not blank
    wallCount ++;
    System.err.println(post.message);
}
```

Will get you the last 15 messages on the authenticated user's wall from others. Some of the messages are blank, which is why I have the null check.